# 3d vector - how to test if another vector is antiparallel

Tags: javascript, class, vector

How to test if another vector is antiparallel?

I am writing a solution in a Codewars kata, the challenge being to create a Javascript class for a 3d vector with 3 members (i,j, and k). I like the challenge, but don't seem to be able to find a formula to determine a vectors' direction without endpoints (or I'd be done). The anti-parallel is a vector in the opposite direction, and I keep getting caught up in the isParallelTo(Vector) method. 
I have coded most of the solution (still have an issue with the isPerpendicularTo(Vector) method, but I'll figure that when I get there.

Full code for context (and to show I'm not asking anyone to do my homework ;-)):

```
    // Helper function - Javascript is peculiar with it's floating point no.s
    function rnd(n){
       return Math.round(n * 1000000)/1000000;
    }

    class Vector {
       constructor(i,j,k) {
         this.i = i;
         this.j = j;
         this.k = k;
         this.magnitude = Math.sqrt( this.i*this.i + this.j*this.j + this.k*this.k );
       }

       // Magnitude (distance)
       getMagnitude() { return this.magnitude; }

       // Unit vectors - i
       static getI() { return new Vector(1, 0, 0); }
       // Unit vectors - j
       static getJ() { return new Vector(0, 1, 0); }
       // Unit vectors - i
       static getK() { return new Vector(0, 0, 1); }

       // Add this vector to another
       add(V) { return new Vector(V.i + this.i, V.j + this.j, V.k + this.k); }

       // Scalar multiply
       multiplyByScalar(m) { return new Vector(m * this.i, m * this.j, m * this.k); }

       // Dot product
       dot(V) { return V.i*this.i + V.j*this.j + V.k*this.k; }

       // Cross product
       cross(V) { return new Vector(this.j*V.k - this.k*V.j, this.k*V.i - this.i*V.k, this.i*V.j - this.j*V.i); }

       // Zero vector? (another helper function, vector specific)
       isZeroVector(V) { return V.i === 0 && V.j === 0 && V.k === 0; }

       // Parallel? unit vectors must be equal
       isParallelTo(V) {
          return !this.isZeroVector(V) && !this.isZeroVector(this) && ( Math.abs(rnd(V.i/this.i)) === Math.abs(rnd(V.j/this.j)) ) && (Math.abs(rnd(V.i/this.i)) === Math.abs(rnd(V.k/this.k)));
       }

       // Perpendicular? 
       isPerpendicularTo(V) {
          return !this.isZeroVector(V) && !this.isZeroVector(this) && this.dot(V) === 0;
       }

       // Normalize
       normalize() { return new Vector(this.i/this.magnitude, this.j/this.magnitude, this.k/this.magnitude); }

       // Normalized already?
       isNormalized() { return rnd(this.magnitude) === rnd(1); }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not going to write a code example but I can give you the math.

It seems that you are storing your vector as an (i, j, k) 3-tuple. This makes (i, j, k) your endpoint (I'm assuming that (0, 0, 0) is the start point for every vector).

One of the formulas for a dot product is:

```
a · b = |a| × |b| × cos(θ)
```

To get anti-parallel you want θ = τ/2 and so cos(τ/2) = -1

So all you need to check is:

```
(a · b) / (|a| × |b|) = -1

dot(a, b)/(a.magnitude*b.magnitude) == -1
```

Comment: I should point out, in the formula above θ is the angle between the 2 vectors. That is why if you want anti-parallel you need θ = τ/2.

Comment: If you are working with floating point numbers, you may not get exactly -1. Instead maybe try Math.abs(dot(a, b)/(a.magnitude*b.magnitude) - 1) < epsilon where epsilon is some really small value.